# ASP Menu control with XML file loading is too slow

Tags: css, asp.net, xml

My question is about menus with ASP.Net and XML
I am using 3 things over here - ASP menu control in the Master file, XML file from where menus are loading to the control.
ASP Code:

```
<div  class="menuxml">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" RenderingMode="List" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" >
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="Menu" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value"
                NavigateUrlField="Url" />
            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SubMenu" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value"
                NavigateUrlField="Url" />
        </DataBindings>
        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="main_menu" />
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level_menu" />
        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Files/menus.xml" XPath="/Menus/Menu"></asp:XmlDataSource>
</div>
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menus>
  <Menu Url="~/" Text="Home" Value="Home Page" />
  <Menu Url="~/icp/" Text="Coding problems" Value="Coding problems" />
  <Menu Url="javascript:;" Text="DS &amp; Algo. &#9662;" Value="DS &amp; Algo.">
    <SubMenu Url ="~/data-structure-tutorial/" Text="Data Structure" Value="Data Structure"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/algorithms/" Text="Algorithms" Value="Algorithms"></SubMenu>
  </Menu>
  <Menu Url="javascript:;" Text="Languages &#9662;" Value="Languages">
    <SubMenu Url ="~/c/" Text="C" Value="C language"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/cpp-tutorial/" Text="C++" Value="C++ language"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/stl/" Text="C++ STL" Value="C++ STL"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/java/" Text="Java" Value="Java language"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/python/" Text="Python" Value="Python language"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/dot-net/" Text="C#.Net" Value="C#.Net"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/android/" Text="Android" Value="Android"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/kotlin/" Text="Kotlin" Value="Kotlin"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/sql/" Text="SQL" Value="SQL"></SubMenu>
  </Menu>
...
..
```

CSS file:

```
  <style>
    .menuxml{
    background-color: #006969;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 95%;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .main_menu,
    .main_menu:visited,
    .main_menu:hover {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .main_menu:hover {
    background-color: #004949;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

    .level_menu,
    .level_menu:visited,
    .level_menu:hover {
    min-width: 100px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .level_menu:hover {
    background-color: #004949;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
```

**Problem is:**
Menus are taking around .5 to .7 seconds to loan and meanwhile its layout is very disturbing on the website in all devices:
Disturbed layout is (for less than a second):
[image]

**After loading the perfect layout is:**

[image]

**Question?**
Is there any way to make them fast, as I analysed its neither a site load issue nor CSS Issue. Please help me!!

Comment: The menu is a part of the page so it *is* load issue. The DOM is already loaded but CSS is *not* applied yet. You can a) hide menu while loading and show when ready (using JS) b) load sub-menus dynamically on client `click` or `hover` event.

Comment: there is no control over here - ASP menu control simply loads the menu from the XML and make them in UL, LI format.

Comment: One more time. The ASP menu is included into HTML of the page and is a part of its DOM. The issue is **client side** and should be addressed on client.

Comment: I removed the CSS and then tested - in this case for the same time of period menus displays as list format at left side - just like simple list and after .5 or .7 seconds menus displays as normal (a horizontal bar). So it should not be issue with the CSS

Comment: Try to do like this. `(css) .menuxml{display:none}` then `(js) $(document).ready(function(){ $('.menuxml').show();});`

Comment: it is working, but another issue is that - for that time period (.5 to .7 seconds) menu does not load - kindly check it live here (refresh the page some of the times and check the load time) https://www.includehelp.com/ if it is acceptable then okay

Answer (score 0):

Request you to kindly follow below solution and share your observation :

**You can bind the menu through Jquery in document.ready section.**

Comment: I just want to keep asp.net control - I worked it for a week to make perfect + responsive etc.